# imu_filter_madgwick does not compile properly on Ubuntu18.04 - Melodic

Tags: ros, filter, ros-melodic, ubuntu, ubuntu-bionic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I downloaded the `imu_filter_madgwick` tool from [here](https://github.com/ccny-ros-pkg/imu_tools) and installed on my `catkin_ws`. Unfortunately it does not compile and the problem is due to the file [imu_filter_nodelet.cpp](https://github.com/ccny-ros-pkg/imu_tools/blob/indigo/imu_filter_madgwick/src/imu_filter_nodelet.cpp).

As I compile the project I receive the following error from the compiler.

```
`/home/emanuele/catkin_ws/src/imu_tools/imu_filter_madgwick/src/imu_filter_nodelet.cpp:39:24: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ‘(’ token
 PLUGINLIB_DECLARE_CLASS(imu_filter_madgwick, ImuFilterNodelet, ImuFilterNodelet, nodelet::Nodelet);`
```

That seems to be due to the following line     `PLUGINLIB_DECLARE_CLASS(imu_filter_madgwick, ImuFilterNodelet, ImuFilterNodelet, nodelet::Nodelet);` in the **.cpp** file below:

```
#include "imu_filter_madgwick/imu_filter_nodelet.h"
#include <pluginlib/class_list_macros.h>

void ImuFilterNodelet::onInit()
{
  NODELET_INFO("Initializing IMU Filter Nodelet");
  
  // TODO: Do we want the single threaded or multithreaded NH?
  ros::NodeHandle nh         = getMTNodeHandle();
  ros::NodeHandle nh_private = getMTPrivateNodeHandle();

  filter_.reset(new ImuFilterRos(nh, nh_private));
}

PLUGINLIB_DECLARE_CLASS(imu_filter_madgwick, ImuFilterNodelet, ImuFilterNodelet, nodelet::Nodelet);
```

After doing some research I found out that the `PLUGINLIB_DECLARE_CLASS...` is deprecated and should be substituted with the following line: `PLUGINLIB_EXPORT_CLASS(imu_filter_madgwick, ImuFilterNodelet, ImuFilterNodelet, nodelet::Nodelet);`

However as I try to compile the project I get a different compilation error which can be seen below:

```
`PLUGINLIB_EXPORT_CLASS" passed 4 arguments, but takes just 2
 ASS(imu_filter_madgwick, ImuFilterNodelet, ImuFilterNodelet, nodelet::Nodelet);
                                                                              ^
/home/emanuele/catkin_ws/src/imu_tools/imu_filter_madgwick/src/imu_filter_nodelet.cpp:39:1: error: ‘PLUGINLIB_EXPORT_CLASS’ does not name a type
 PLUGINLIB_EXPORT_CLASS(imu_filter_madgwick, ImuFilterNodelet, ImuFilterNodelet, nodelet::Nodelet);`
```

It seems that no matter what I substitute I can't make `catkin_ws` to work correctly.
Is there something that I am missing or can someone point in the right direction on what the problem could be?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/323682/imu_filter_madgwick-does-not-compile-properly-on-ubuntu18.04---melodic/) by [RayROS](https://answers.ros.org/users/40704/rayros/) on ROS Answers with karma: 108 on 2019-05-21

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2019-05-21**:
Please don't use images to post text. Images are not searchable and the text in the images cannot be copied and pasted. Please update your question with a copy and paste of the text instead. See [the support page](https://wiki.ros.org/Support#Do) for further information.

**Comment by [RayROS](https://answers.ros.org/users/40704/rayros/) on 2019-05-21**:
Thanks jayess for the comment. I just update the question with the text.

**Comment by [KennyDeDavion](https://answers.ros.org/users/72611/kennydedavion/) on 2021-09-29**:
sudo apt install ros-melodic-imu-filter-madgwick , now not function.
Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> Hello, I downloaded the `imu_filter_madgwick` tool from [here](https://github.com/ccny-ros-pkg/imu_tools) and installed on my `catkin_ws`.

First question: why? Do you need to compile it from source?

`imu_filter_madgwick` has been released into Melodic quite some time ago (see [the wiki page](http://wiki.ros.org/imu_filter_madgwick?distro=melodic)) making installation a simple `sudo apt install ros-melodic-imu-filter-madgwick`.

Unless you have a good reason to build from source I would recommend you install the binaries.

> However as I try to compile the project I get a different compilation error which can be seen below:

> ```
> `PLUGINLIB_EXPORT_CLASS" passed 4 arguments, but takes just 2
> ```

```
 ASS(imu_filter_madgwick, ImuFilterNodelet, ImuFilterNodelet, nodelet::Nodelet);
                                                                              ^
/home/emanuele/catkin_ws/src/imu_tools/imu_filter_madgwick/src/imu_filter_nodelet.cpp:39:1: error: ‘PLUGINLIB_EXPORT_CLASS’ does not name a type
 PLUGINLIB_EXPORT_CLASS(imu_filter_madgwick, ImuFilterNodelet, ImuFilterNodelet, nodelet::Nodelet);`
```

The correct syntax would be (from [here](https://github.com/ccny-ros-pkg/imu_tools/blob/54160b300b94d4904e8423fc7aa73802a7138855/imu_filter_madgwick/src/imu_filter_nodelet.cpp#L39)):

```
PLUGINLIB_EXPORT_CLASS(ImuFilterNodelet, nodelet::Nodelet);
```

It's not just the name that changed, the arguments have changed as well.

This was changed in the Melodic version of the package about 2 years ago (in [ccny-ros-pkg/imu_tools#77](https://github.com/ccny-ros-pkg/imu_tools/pull/77)). If you'd install the binaries, you'd not have to make this change.

It would also appear you're trying to build the Indigo version on ROS Melodic. If you must build the package(s) from source, use the `melodic` branch.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-05-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [RayROS](https://answers.ros.org/users/40704/rayros/) on 2019-05-22**:
Hello gvdhoorn and thanks for your detailed answer and for providing the latest version of the `imu_filter_madgwick`. And yes, I installed it using the `Melodic` version you indicated and now it works very well. :)

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-05-22**:
So did you need to build the package from source, or did you install it using `apt`?

**Comment by [RayROS](https://answers.ros.org/users/40704/rayros/) on 2019-05-22**:
I installed the binaries as you advised `sudo apt install ros-melodic-imu-filter-madgwick`. I was trying to build it from source only because I could not find a `Melodic` version. The only one that I found was the `Indigo` which did not carry the corrected syntax and the one cointained in the `git` repo I posted in the question.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I just compiled imu_filter_madgwick on Rpi4 Debian Buster for Melodic!
So if you need to compile it from source and the preferred

```
sudo apt install ros-melodic-imu-filter-madgwick
```

does not work, like on Buster for the moment, you need to
git checkout on the melodic branch first!

```
$ cd catkin_ws/src

$ git clone https://github.com/ccny-ros-pkg/imu_tools.git

$ cd imu_tools

$ git checkout melodic



=> Your branch is up to date with 'origin/melodic'.
```

Now `catkin_make` will compile everything!

---

Originally posted by [arminf82](https://answers.ros.org/users/45412/arminf82/) with karma: 31 on 2019-09-08

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3